# Change bullet color on hover wrapped in <a>

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color of all the bullets in this `<ul>` when hovering the `<a>`.
I tried many things, but the only thing that seems to work is: using pseudo elements. When you run that code below, you will see - the bullets color doesn't change **on hover**.

HTML

```
<a>
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dollar is great</li>
        <li>Dollar is better bio element</li>
    </ul>              
</a>
```

CSS

```
a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: black; 
}

a:hover {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: green; 
}
```

[A link to the code. jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Peleori/f35nt56x/)

Are there solutions **without using pseudo elements and without using graphics in list-style?**

Comment: Your code looks good to me, although I'd probably use `a:hover ul` instead of just `a:hover`. Why do you want to do this without using pseudo elements?

Comment: @vaultah Because you need to style the pseudo elements and remove the original bullets.

Comment: but using pseudo elements gives you better control over your styling.I personally prefer pseudo over default

Comment: @Anonymous.X You might be right - but I am curious if there is a solution without pseudo elements.

Comment: @Peter now check to this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f35nt56x/8/

Comment: @RohitAzad You use pseudo elements in your answer. So no - that's not a posible answer to my question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/f35nt56x/9/ check this

Comment: it's changing @Peter

Comment: @Peter I'm sorry! But it's working for me in Google Chrome 43

Comment: Your fiddle works for me in FF (bullets and text turn green on hover) but not in Chrome (only text turns green on hover).

Comment: Looks like a chrome bug to me. Look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/woestijnrog/mrxt66yg/) in Chrome and in Firefox.

Comment: Using a Pseudo element is absolutely the best and most supported way of doing this.

Comment: @woestijnrog When I try your fiddle in chrome only decimal list style changes its color on hover but the bullets don't change. I know they change in firefox. It might be a bug. But who knows`?

Comment: @Peter I've found a [workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/woestijnrog/oqy0hw5d/). Maybe that works for you?

Comment: @woestijnrog Indeed - it is working. You might post it as an answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bullets, i.e. `list-style-types`, should inherit the [currentColor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#currentColor_keyword).

When the color changes on hover Chrome 'forgets' to redraw the bullets. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/woestijnrog/mrxt66yg/) for an example of the difference of Chrome vs other browsers. So how do we trick Chrome into redrawing the bullets without pseudo-elements and without graphics? By fiddling with the margins and the padding. There are multiple ways to style a default bulleted list, by forcing Chrome to switch from one way to another it redraws the bullets too.

```css
    #one:hover, #two:hover {
        color: red;
    }
    #two{
        margin-left: 40px;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
    #two:hover{
        margin-left: 0px;
        padding-left: 40px;
    }
```

```html
    <ul id='one'>
        <li>In Chrome:</li>
        <li>The bullets don't change colour</li>
        <li>when you hover over this list.</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id='two'>
        <li>The bullets change colour</li>
        <li>in all browsers</li>
    </ul>
```