# List-item not changing style correctly JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to ask a question about JQuery, which I've recently started to use.

I have an ol list, and I would like to change the background and font color of selected list-item (active list item). So I've written a code like this :

```js
$('.cart-list ol li').on('click', function() {
  $('.active-cart-list').removeClass('active-cart-list');
  $(this).addClass('active-cart-list');
});
```

```css
.cart-list ol li {
  margin-top: 1px;
  padding: 5px 16px 5px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.cart-list ol li>span {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 28px;
}
.cart-list ol li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cart-list ol li.active-cart-list {
  background-color: #e571c5;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart-list">
  <ol>
    <li class="active-cart-list"><span>lorem1</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>lorem2</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>lorem3</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>lorem4</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>lorem5</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>lorem6</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>lorem7</span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

[image: list-style-item problem]

List items change their color properly once list is scrolled down, but I can't expect to have a scroll on every list at that website. I would be really pleased to get any help.

Cheers

Comment: Change that in the CSS. It will work. `:)`

Comment: Changed it, hopefully it looks better

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33516623/change-bullet-color-on-hover-wrapped-in-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is not a jQuery problem, it's a CSS one.

List bullets/numbers are hard to change once set...this is probably an excellent case for CSS Counters.

```js
$('.cart-list ol li').on('click', function() {
  $('.active-cart-list').removeClass('active-cart-list');
  $(this).addClass('active-cart-list');
});
```

```css
.cart-list ol li {
  margin-top: 1px;
  padding: 5px 16px 5px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
ol {
  counter-reset: numbers;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li::before {
  counter-increment: numbers;
  content: counters(numbers, "")". ";
}
.cart-list ol li>span {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 28px;
}
.cart-list ol li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.cart-list ol li.active-cart-list {
  background-color: #e571c5;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart-list">
  <ol>
    <li class="active-cart-list"><span>lorem1</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>lorem2</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>lorem3</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>lorem4</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>lorem5</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>lorem6</span>
    </li>
    <li><span>lorem7</span>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Well it worked like a charm, I really appreciate Your help. Never before made "custom" <ol> without using it, but I think i'll start because of some JQuery problems though. Thanks once again!